# Ionic 3 Prevent app exit

Tags: ionic, ionic2, ionic3

Fiz uma aplicação utilizando Ionic 3. Quando esta na tela principal e caso o usuário clica no botão voltar o aplicativo é encerrado.

Queria colocar um "prevent appexit" que verifica que o usuário esta na tela principal e não deixa realizar nenhum evento.

Answer (score 1):

Tente:

```
platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
    // ACAO que deseja que seja realizada.
});
```